# Failure on installing htop on the server

Tags: server, apt, software-installation

I'm trying to install `htop` on my server *(ubuntu 14.04)*. Here is the command:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

But it throws:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package htop
```

Noted that it throws `E: Unable to locate package ....` for everything I would like to install *(like `phpmyadmin`)*. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **`htop`** package is in the repository 'universe'. The following commands should work to install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install htop
```

or as `root`

```
add-apt-repository universe

apt-get update
apt-get install htop
```

Comment: The result of your first command: `'universe' distribution component enabled for all sources.`

Comment: I use `htop` and I install it as described here. What is the output of your update and install commands?

Comment: update happens successfully, but `E: Unable to locate package htop` is still there when I try to install htop. Can you please take a look at my server if I give you user and password?

Comment: How would you send me user and password in a secure way? Maybe you can use gpg encryption and my public key, that you find at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/gui/tarball

Comment: My server is empty *(almost)*, so I don't care about security, if you give me your email, I will send it to you. Just do you have Putty installed on your computer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70423/discussion-between-sudodus-and-stack).

Comment: Emaul has been sent

Comment: did you get my email?

Comment: @stack, Yes. Please see my messages in the chat room (and let me know if things are working now).

Comment: In case anyone gets the error `add-apt-repository command not found`, first install the software properties common: `apt-get install software-properties-common`.

Comment: I got the same issue as the `add-apt-repository command not found` but luckily I fixed my problem with `sudo apt-get update` i did not update the system before installing the new package.